# In gtk3+ for python how to get selected menuitem or index of menuitem selected?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

```
def search(self,button):
    print 'search clicked'
    self.popup_menu=Gtk.Menu()
    s=self.search_field.get_text()
    if s:
        href, title, size, seeders, leechers= scrape_test.main() 
        for i in range(len(href)):

            i1 = Gtk.MenuItem(str(i+1)+'. '+title[i]+' '+size[i]+'       '+seeders[i]+' '+leechers[i])
            self.popup_menu.append(i1)
            print ' '
        self.popup_menu.show_all()
        self.popup_menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, Gtk.get_current_event_time())
```

popup shows up the menu but what i want to get the selected menuitem or the index of selected menuitem. How can i do so?

Comment: Did you try `self.popup_menu.get_active()`?

Comment: Yes it always returns 1st menuitem cause it gets called before i click the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you have to connect handlers to the "activate" event of each MenuItem. Something like this:

```
def search(self):
    print("search clicked")
    self.popup_menu = Gtk.Menu()
    s = "Some text to test "
    if s:
        for i in range(5):
            i1 = Gtk.MenuItem(s + str(i))
            self.popup_menu.append(i1)
            i1.connect("activate", self.item_activated, i)
            print(' ')
        self.popup_menu.show_all()
        self.popup_menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, \
                              Gtk.get_current_event_time())

def item_activated(self, wdg, i):
    print('Item activated ', i)
```

I've simplified the actual texts for the menuitems, because I don't have the functions to get the actual texts.